# egg_info errors installing ipython

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm having issues installing ipython with `sudo pip install "ipython[notebook]"`.
The error that I am seeing is

`Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-Jzcy1W/terminado`

Any ideas on how I can resolve this?

Comment: What version of `pip` are you using?

Comment: pip version is 7.0.1 using python 2.7

Comment: On what system? I just tried to replicate this, and it's all working OK for me.

Comment: If I remember correctly this is Mac OS X 10.7

Comment: The error message suggests that the problem is with terminado. If you try installing terminado by itself (still with pip), is there still an error? And does the output provide any more information about what went wrong?

Comment: `pip install terminado` results in this error: `Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/3s/ljj_w2f93b52q49f97tmdqph0000gn/T/pip-build-2PBw75/terminado`

Comment: `sudo pip install terminado` give this error message: `Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-LBRMrf/terminado`

Comment: @mnickey, and setuptools is also up-to-date?

Comment: With an error like that, there's usually another message a bit above it with more detail about what went wrong. Is that really the only thing it's showing you?

Comment: @ThomasK yes, that's really all that there is. However, thanks @cel for asking if setuptools was up-to-date. It wasn't. It was severely outdated. After updating that with `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -o - | python` we're back in business.

thanks everyone! :)

Answer (score 1):

In this case the issue seemed to be that setuptools was outdated. By updating setuptools `pip install "ipython[notebook]"` went through flawlessly and I am able to work in the interactive shell nicely.
Thanks to all that helped track this down.

Answer (score 0):

**egg_info errors installing ipython in windows**

Right. I also faced this problem and later I updated setuptools and went for installing ipython.

To update setuptools run windows command and type :

```
python -m pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Then, install ipython using pip:

```
pip install ipython
```

> I am using python in windows and newbie. So your experienced problem
>   and solution might be helpful for me and others. Thanks!